Use Cellular Data while Maintaining Connection to Offline Wifi Hotspot
For a project I'm doing, I want to maintain a connection to an offline wifi hotspot. I want to do this so I can interact with the device wirelessly.
I want to also, at the same time, be able to use my phone to browse the internet.
So
Device A : 100% offline. Wifi Hotspot Emitting.
Device B : Phone. Connected to Wifi Hotspot. Use Cellular Data for internet.
Is this possible? I have the newest iPhone with the newest iOS if it helps. I have Wifi Assist turned on in Cellular Settings, but it seems that just puts you on Cellular when the Wifi internet is poor (thus killing my connection to Device A).

The hotspot is for connection to a LAN?

I think you can use the WiFi Assist feature for this. See https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251188571?sortBy=rank

@Barmar Wifi Assist actually disconnects you from the wifi and tries to reconnect you when it regains internet, but since this is an internetless wifi, it seems it never reconnects.
